# Internal coding or implementation of Trigger.New

Tags: apex, trigger, api, triggercontext

I want to know internal implementation like API or method or internal coding for Trigger.new.How it works.How the API trigger.new works.Anyone having any details for trigger.new

Comment: Robert, it will be great if you can elaborate your question bit more. Trigger.new is database level event so it works same as frontend though some steps are not there.

Comment: For example:We use collections like Map,list etc which has internal implementation,internal coding.Similar there will be for Trigger.new.How this event works internally.What all coding involved internally when we just call Trigger.new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce platform is not open source so the code is not available. Instead Salesforce documents APIs and provides examples and training material.

A key reference document in this area is [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Trigger.new is a list of sObjects and can be iterated over in a for loop as the same way we iterate over any other sObject list.

Try to print

```
System.debug('*****************'+ Trigger.new);
```

You will get your answer.

Comment: I know above things but how does internally it works.There would be some apex class apex method involved for trigger.new,the same i want to know.

Comment: can you see List Class apex code? These are the internal class of SFDC. code is not exposed.

Comment: In java we can see internal class.is there way in salesforce to see internal class code ?

Comment: no, It is not permitted.